# Is it possible to write text file then upload to google drive in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-picker

i'm trying to write string to text file then upload to google drive
is it possible via javascript or using react-google-picker ?

here's my code to download file to my local storage...

```
    Download= () => {
        var _this = this;
        const element = document.createElement("a");
        const file = new Blob([_this.state.xmldata], { type: 'text/plain' });
        element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        element.download = "text.txt";
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        element.click();
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is if google drive has an api that enables you to create a file. This isn't really react specific.

- https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/bd53b366aedef70e35a35f449c51eced
- [User uploaded file to google drive via javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32272188/user-uploaded-file-to-google-drive-via-javascript)
- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create

I believe you'll find the 3rd link to be the most useful. Essentially, you just need to post the file to their rest api with your authentication:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files
```

Here is the full API Documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/

Comment: hi, yeah thanks for the answer.yes the third link is what I want. Can you provide me with example. i'm kind of confused because the documentary not really clear how to implement it in frontend. Thank you and sry english is not my native language